# How to resize a dropdown search preview results for small screen resolutions (Angular, Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll, header, popup

I can't figure out how to solve the following issue. On the website I have a show-and-hide sticky header which looks like this https://stackblitz.com/github/zetsnotdead/ng-reactive-sticky-header. The header contains a pop-up menu and pop-up search results (4 most popular results + "show all" button). If the screen resolution is 1366 x 768 or smaller this search result preview doesn't fit the screen and 4th result and "show all" button are beyond it. And scrolling down, as I've already said, hides the whole header including these search results, so it's impossible to click the button.

Unfortunately we don't follow 'mobile first'principle. And all the adaptive layout depends on bootstrap in general.

So how can I make the search results pop-up to fit any screen resolutions without adding mediarequests? Is it possible? I can't find any way.
If any additional info is required, I can provide you with it.
I'm sorry in advance, I'm a nubee here.

Comment: You can (maybe) try to find the screen resolution using javascript and then add/remove classes based on the resolution you found with js, but I don't recommend it. Also, bootstrap provides some utility classes to show/hide elements based on the resolution. : https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/ maybe this can point you to the right direction

Comment: Uses the bootstrap containers, rows, and cols. This is effective for multiple screen sizes